# What's the right way to use several webdriver of selenium simultaneously?

Tags: python, selenium, concurrency

The goal is to write a python script that opens a specific website, fills out some inputs and then submits it. This should be done with different inputs for the same website simultaneously.

I tried using Threads from threading and some other things but i can't make it work simultaneously.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from threading import Thread


def test_function():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get("https://www.google.com")
    time.sleep(3)


if __name__ =='__main__':
    Thread(target = test_function()).start()
    Thread(target = test_function()).start()
```

So executing this code the goal is that 2 chrome windows will open simultaneously, go to google and then wait for 3 seconds. Now all that's done is that the function is called two times in a serial manner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now all that's done is that the function is called
>   two times in a serial manner.

The behavior you are seeing is because you are calling `test_function()` when you pass it as a target.  Rather than calling the function, just assign the callable name (`test_function`).

like this:

```
Thread(target=test_function).start()
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need a testing framework like pytest to execute tests in parallel. Here is a quick setup guide to get you going.

[PythonWebdriverParallel](https://www.seleniumeasy.com/python/pytest-run-webdriver-tests-in-parallel)